# SVN copy vs checkout for creating a branch

Tags: svn

Trying to figure out how to make a branch, usually someone else makes them and I just go in and work with them, so my SVN knowledge is a bit basic. Today I need to make a branch based on the working copy in trunk. However I'm trying to search around and find my answer so I don't come here asking something that may be a dupe question, and all things I have found either don't really answer my question or don't apply well to my overall need

from what I gather

```
svn copy ~/my/branches/destination https://example.com/svn/my/trunk/ -m 'Message about creation of Branch'
```

should work for me, but it does not appear to be the case. Currently I am getting an error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Which lead me to wonder if `copy` is what I want to do. So this is a brand new branch being created, I need advice on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If `~/my/branches/destination` is Working Copy, prepared for branch, then `svn copy SRC[@REV]... DST` will be translated to

```
svn copy ~/my/branches/destination https://example.com/svn/branches/branchname ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after much playing around, I realized my problem. I was trying to combine the logic of remote and local.

I had to first make the branch on the remote server that is the repo, then turn around and checkout the copy of the branch from the server.